# Pandas delete duplicate rows based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, group-by

I have a dataset where I have multiple duplicate records based on timestamps for the same date. I want to keep the record with the max timestamp and delete the other records for a given ID and timestamp combo.

Sample dataset

```
id|timestamp|value
--|---------|-----
1|2022-04-19T18:46:36.259+0000|xyz
1|2022-04-19T18:46:36.302+0000|xyz
1|2022-04-19T18:46:36.357+0000|xyz
1|2022-04-24T00:41:40:871+0000|xyz
1|2022-04-24T00:41:40:879+0000|xyz
1|2022-05-02T10:15:25.829+0000|xyz
1|2022-05-02T10:15:25.832+0000|xyz
```

Final Df

```
id|timestamp|value
--|---------|-----

1|2022-04-19T18:46:36.357+0000|xyz
1|2022-04-24T00:41:40:879+0000|xyz
1|2022-05-02T10:15:25.832+0000|xyz
```

Comment: No Images, please review the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited the Question , please review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add the data as a code, it'll be easier to share the result. Since you already have a data, its simpler to post it as a code or text

```
# To keep the lastdate but latest timestamp
# create a dateonly field from timestamp, in identifying the dupicates
# sort values so, we have latest timestamp for an id at the end
# drop duplicates based on id and timestamp. keeping last row
# finally drop the temp column

(df.assign(d=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.date)
 .sort_values(['id','timestamp'])
 .drop_duplicates(subset=['id','d'], keep='last')
 .drop(columns='d')
)
```

```
    id  timestamp   value
2   1   2022-04-19T18:46:36.357+0000    xyz
4   1   2022-04-24T00:41:40.879+0000    xyz
6   1   2022-05-02T10:15:25.832+0000    xyz
```

Comment: I have posted an edited Dataframe copy. Can you check now ? I am looking to find max of diff timestamp for the same ID.

Comment: @Datamaniac, did the updated solution worked? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

a combination of .groupby and .max will do

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.to_datetime(['01-01-1990', '01-02-1990', '01-02-1990', '01-03-1990'])
values = [1] * len(dates)
ids = values[:]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(dates, values, ids), columns=['timestamp', 'val', 'id'])

selection = df.groupby(['val', 'id'])['timestamp'].max().reset_index()

print(selection)
```

output

```
   val  id  timestamp
0    1   1 1990-01-03
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for your task.

```
df.groupby(["id","value"]).max()
```

explanation: Fist group by using id and value column and then select only the maximum.